# After open attachment page events not work in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, attachment

On a page, i open an attachment on link button click by set PostBackUrl as

```
lnkCalendar.PostBackUrl = "AddScheduleToCalendar.aspx?scheduleGuid=" + scheduleGuid;
```

After save or close attachment, currentlly open web page buttons click still open same attachement again thier own click event donot work. If untill not click attachment link buttom events work.
Code of attachmnet on AddScheduleToCalendar.aspx page's load method is

```
string calendarFormat = GetScheduleInfo();
            Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyCalendar.ics");
            Response.Write(calendarFormat);
            Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you postback to open attachments your page lifecycle is performed again.

My best guess is that you are not assigning the PostBackUrls while loading the attachment.

Provide more information about how you load those attachments.